# Print letter by letter using Tkinter

Tags: python, text, tkinter

Is there a way to print letter by letter (redraw between frame update) in Python 3.4.1 using Tkinter?

This is doable in the normal IDLE window using this piece of code:

```
import time
string = "hello world"
for char in string:
    print(char, end='')
    time.sleep(.25)
```

But I can't do this in GUI Tkinter window. In my opinion, I could display a label on to the tkinter window, add a letter from a string into it, and wait for a period of time before adding another letter (about 0.25 secs), with the same idea as the code above. 
Any solutions?

For example:

**String To Display** = 'abc'

*First* frame : 'a'

*Second* frame : 'ab'

*Third* Frame : 'abc'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Print them frame by frame? Like, redraw between the letters.

Comment: You can do this, yes, but how exactly would you want to do it?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question a bit.

Comment: Please show your code that doesn't work.

Comment: Your first step needs to be to work through a tkinter tutorial. Once you understand the basics, try to write a program that does when you want. If it doesn't work, try to research why. Only after you do all that should you come back here to ask a question. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Comment: I have written a program for this, but it can only be used backward, but I want it forward, appeared letter by letter AFTER the window has turn on

Comment: And did you know any tutorial site, apart from tutorialpoint.com?

Comment: See `tkinter` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tkinter/info) for more resources such as tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify much so I just guessed you'd like something like this:

```
import time
import tkinter as tk


def printString(string):
    for char in string:
        Label.configure(text=Label.cget('text') + char)
        Label.update()
        time.sleep(.25)

root = tk.Tk()
text = "Hello world!"
Label = tk.Label(root)
Label.pack()
printString(text)
root.mainloop()
```

---

UPDATE:

Same principle but for a `canvas`:

```
import time
import tkinter as tk


def printString(item, string):
    if item:
        for char in string:
            idx = c.index(item, tk.END)
            c.insert(item, idx, char)
            c.update()
            time.sleep(.25)


root = tk.Tk()
text = "Hello world!"
c = tk.Canvas(root)
c_txt = c.create_text(50,50)
c.pack()
c.update()
printString(c_txt, text)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1487, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\World Defence System 2.py", line 9, in printString
    Label.configure(text=Label.cget('text') + char)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1272, in cget
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".36117616"

Comment: Is there a way to active the printString() command without using a button?

Comment: @hungnguyen I've editted it, so it starts playing as soon as you run it. Is that more like the way you intended it?

Comment: So, the line  :                                    
Label.configure(text=Label.cget('text') + char), it means that the label add a new letter every time it runs?

Comment: And could you do this on a canvas?

Comment: @hungnguyen do you mean with `canvas.create_text`?

Comment: Yes, please, as I'm running a simulation, and need graphic as well @ViG

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) to call a method periodically to update the GUI. `time.sleep` is *not* as easy to work with as it blocks main-thread which the GUI runs on.

---

You could periodically ***replace*** the `label`'s *single character* text ***with next letter in the string***:

```
 try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk


def update_label_letter():
    global label
    label['text'] = label.string[label.current_char_index]
    label.current_char_index += 1
    label.current_char_index %= len(label.string)
    label.after(250, update_label_letter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    label = tk.Label(root)
    label.string = "Hello World!"
    label.current_char_index = 0
    root.after(250, update_label_letter)
    label.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

---

One way would be to periodically ***append* the letters** of a *single* `label`.

**Vertical:**

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk


def update_label_letters():
    global label
    _no_of_space_replacements = label['text'].count('\n')
    _last_char_index = len(label['text']) - _no_of_space_replacements
    if _last_char_index < len(label.string):
        label['text'] += label.string[_last_char_index].replace(" ", " \n")
    else:
        label['text'] = ""
    label.after(250, update_label_letters)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    label = tk.Label(root, wraplength=1)
    label.string = "Hello World!"
    root.after(250, update_label_letters)
    label.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

**Horizontal:**

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk


def update_label_letters():
    global label
    _last_char_index = len(label['text'])
    if _last_char_index < len(label.string):
        label['text'] += label.string[_last_char_index]
    else:
        label['text'] = ""
    label.after(250, update_label_letters)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    label = tk.Label(root)
    label.string = "Hello World!"
    root.after(250, update_label_letters)
    label.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

---

Another way would be to ***write the letters*** periodically to empty but shown `letter_labels`.

**Vertical:**

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk


def update_label_letters():
    global current_char_index, my_string, letter_labels
    if current_char_index < len(my_string):
        _current_char = my_string[current_char_index]
        letter_labels[current_char_index]['text'] = _current_char
        letter_labels[current_char_index].after(250, update_label_letters)
        current_char_index += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    my_string = "Hello World!"
    letter_labels = list()
    for index, value in enumerate(my_string):
        letter_labels.append(tk.Label(root))
        letter_labels[index].pack()
    current_char_index = 0
    root.after(250, update_label_letters)
    root.mainloop()
```

**Horizontal:**

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk


def update_label_letters():
    global current_char_index, my_string, letter_labels
    if current_char_index < len(my_string):
        _current_char = my_string[current_char_index]
        letter_labels[current_char_index]['text'] = _current_char
        letter_labels[current_char_index].after(250, update_label_letters)
        current_char_index += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    my_string = "Hello World!"
    letter_labels = list()
    for index, value in enumerate(my_string):
        letter_labels.append(tk.Label(root))
        letter_labels[index].pack(side='left')
    current_char_index = 0
    root.after(250, update_label_letters)
    root.mainloop()
```

---

Another way would be to ***display*** the `letter_labels` periodically.

**Vertical:**

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk


def show_label():
    global current_char_index, my_string, letter_labels
    if current_char_index < len(my_string):
        letter_labels[current_char_index].pack()
        letter_labels[current_char_index].after(250, show_label)
        current_char_index += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    my_string = "Hello World!"
    letter_labels = list()
    for _char in my_string:
        letter_labels.append(tk.Label(root, text=_char))
    current_char_index = 0
    root.after(250, show_label)
    root.mainloop()
```

**Horizontal:**

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk


def show_label():
    global current_char_index, my_string, letter_labels
    if current_char_index < len(my_string):
        letter_labels[current_char_index].pack(side='left')
        letter_labels[current_char_index].after(250, show_label)
        current_char_index += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    my_string = "Hello World!"
    letter_labels = list()
    for _char in my_string:
        letter_labels.append(tk.Label(root, text=_char))
    current_char_index = 0
    root.after(250, show_label)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It worked, but it's vertical, but I want it horizontally?

Comment: @hungnguyen Sorry. If only I could've _guessed_ that.

Comment: IT WORKED! But is there a way to print the string without the spaces between them?

Comment: @hungnguyen I'm not sure what you mean but the first two solutions have the least amount of spaces.